# How to make jaxb plugin use OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, java-time, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-maven-plugin, cxf-codegen-plugin

We have a xsd with `xs:dateTime` fields. This is our in-house internal API, and we can guarantee that the offset data is always included, so that it's ISO-8601 compatible. For example:

> 2016-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00

Currently, the jaxb2 plugin maps `xs:dateTime` to a field of type `XMLGregorianCalendar`. How to configure the plugin, so that it uses  `OffsetDateTime` instead?

I don't care whether the solution is for `maven-jaxb2-plugin`, `jaxb2-maven-plugin` or `cxf-codegen-plugin`, we'll use whichever works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `jaxb2-maven-plugin` with a `jaxb-bindings` file.

First I created a `odt.xsd` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="teste" type="Teste" />
  <xsd:complexType name="Teste">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="date" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="1"
        maxOccurs="1" nillable="false"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Then I created a `jaxb-bindings.xjb` file, that defines the type of the `date` field, and also the class that converts from and to it:

```
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" jaxb:version="2.0">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="odt.xsd">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='date']">
            <jaxb:javaType name="java.time.OffsetDateTime"
             parseMethod="xsd.test.OffsetDateTimeAdapter.parse"
             printMethod="xsd.test.OffsetDateTimeAdapter.print" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="xsd.test" />
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

This file references the `xsd.test.OffsetDateTimeAdapter` class and the respective methods to convert the `OffsetDateTime` from and to a `String`, so I also created it:

```
package xsd.test;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class OffsetDateTimeAdapter {

    public static OffsetDateTime parse(String value) {
        return OffsetDateTime.parse(value);
    }

    public static String print(OffsetDateTime value) {
        return value.toString();
    }
}
```

Then, in `pom.xml` I've added the configuration for the plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>xjc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>xjc</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- The package of your generated sources -->
        <packageName>xsd.test</packageName>
        <sources>
            <source>src/main/resources/odt.xsd</source>
        </sources>
        <xjbSources>
            <xjbSource>src/main/resources/jaxb-bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
        </xjbSources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With this, I've just built the project with `mvn clean package` and the jar created contains the generated files in the `xsd.test` package. The `Teste` class contains the `date` field as a `OffsetDateTime`:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Teste", propOrder = {
    "date"
})
public class Teste {

    @XmlElement(required = true, type = String.class)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter1 .class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
    protected OffsetDateTime date;
    // getter and setter
}
```

With this, the `date` field is mapped to a `OffsetDateTime`, using the autogenerated `Adapter1` (which internally uses the `xsd.test.OffsetDateTimeAdapter` class created above). Example of parsing the date from a xml:

```
ObjectFactory f = new ObjectFactory();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("xsd.test");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><ns2:teste xmlns:ns2=\"xsd.test\"><date>2016-01-01T00:00+01:00</date></ns2:teste>";
JAXBElement<Teste> jaxElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes())), Teste.class);
OffsetDateTime odt = jaxElement.getValue().getDate();
System.out.println(odt); // 2016-01-01T00:00+01:00
```

And when marshalling the date to a xml, the `OffsetDateTime` is directly converted to a `String` such as `2016-01-01T00:00+01:00`.

---

Another way is to use the command line `xjc`, which comes with the JDK:

```
xjc src/main/resources/odt.xsd -d src/main/java/ -p xsd.test -b src/main/resources/jaxb-bindings.xjb
```

This generates the classes in `src/main/java` directory, at the `xsd.test` package.

Comment: Thank you, this works very well. Only drawback is you have to enumerate all your `xsd:dateTime` elements in the `xjb`. But that's a minor point.

Comment: @LustigerAstronaut You're welcome, glad to help! Maybe you could change the binding to `node="//xsd:element[@type='xsd:dateTime']"` (I haven't tested, though)

Answer (score 1):

[jTextTime library](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTextTime) solves this.

The library revolves around the JDK8 `OffsetXXX` date/time classes as these are the (only) natural equivalent for the XML Schema types `date`, `dateTime` and `time`. It also deals with [differences between XML types and JSR-310 types](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTextTime/wiki/JAXB-type-adapter-classes-for-java.time#differences-between-xml-datetime-types-and-javas-offset-datetime-classes) as there's unfortunately not a one-to-one match.

Use like this:

**Add dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.addicticks.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtexttime</artifactId>
    <version> ... latest ...</version>
</dependency>
```

**Create your XJC binding:**

Create a file named `src/main/xjb/jaxb-datetime-bindings.xjb` with content as below. 
If you are using the JAXB2 Maven Plugin then it will automatically be picked up by the plugin. If you are using another Maven Plugin then you'll have to tell it where to find this file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- This file is automatically picked up by the jaxb2-maven-plugin
         if it lives in src/main/xjb                                -->
<jxb:bindings   
        xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.1">

    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <!-- Avoid having to work with XMLGregorianCalendar. 
             Instead, map as follows:

                 XML dateTime   :   OffsetDateTime  
                 XML date       :   OffsetDateTime  (time value truncated)
                 XML time       :   OffsetTime                             -->

        <xjc:javaType adapter="com.addicticks.texttime.jaxb.OffsetDateTimeXmlAdapter"
                      name="java.time.OffsetDateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime"/>
        <xjc:javaType adapter="com.addicticks.texttime.jaxb.OffsetDateXmlAdapter"
                      name="java.time.OffsetDateTime" xmlType="xs:date"/>
        <xjc:javaType adapter="com.addicticks.texttime.jaxb.OffsetTimeXmlAdapter"
                      name="java.time.OffsetTime" xmlType="xs:time"/>

    </jxb:globalBindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

The *JAXB2 Maven Plugin* will by default pickup all `.xjb` files in `src/main/xjb/` folder, so you don't have to specify the above file in the plugin's config.

The project's [README](https://github.com/Addicticks/jTextTime/blob/master/README.md) has more information on how to use the library.